# Visualforce page usingbase standard controller

Tags: apex, sobject, controller-extension

I have the following Visualforce page and controller:

```
<apex:page  standardController="sObject" extensions="ExtensionController">
    <div>
         {!o.Id}
    </div>
    <div>
        {!o.Name}
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ExtensionController{

    public SObject  o {get;set;}

    public ExtensionController( ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        this.o = stdController.getRecord() ;

        ...API CALL...
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
sObject does not exist
```

Is there any way I can do this? My ultimate goal is to be able to include this page in a few objects' layouts.

Comment: No. It is tied to the API name / sObjectType of the object

Comment: This is about the best you can do: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/792/is-it-possible-to-create-a-reusable-inline-visualforce-page

Comment: For which Salesforce version you are trying to implement it?

Comment: @RuslanVekua API v33

Answer (score 0):

When you are extending a page, in the contructor, you need to type cast the `stdController.getRecord()` value to corresponding object instance. For example `(Contact)stdController.getRecord()`

For your use case what we can do is to create a generic visualforce component which accept ID of the record. Then get further details using that inside component controller and display in page.